# How to make a gen_server reply with a message?

Tags: erlang

I have the gen_server shown below. It works for the most part. However when I start it from the shell the replies come right back to the shell prompt. I would have expected them to be sent as messages back to the shells pid and then I would use flush() to see them.

What do I have to change in order to have the foo_worker send its replies as messages ?

```
-module(foo_worker).
-behaviour(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/1, start/1, init/1, send/3, die/1]).
-export([handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2]).

%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------

send(Worker, Ref, Counter) ->
  gen_server:call(Worker, {inc, Ref, Counter}).

die(Worker) ->
  gen_server:cast(Worker, die).

%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------

start_link(Limit) ->
  gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [Limit], []).

start(Limit) ->
  gen_server:start(?MODULE, [Limit], []).

init([Limit]) ->
  {ok, Limit}.

handle_call(_, _, Limit) when Limit =< 0 ->
  exit({worker, eol});
handle_call({inc, Ref, Data}, From, Limit) ->
  io:format("From ~p~n", [From]),
  {reply, {Ref, updated, Data+1}, Limit - 1}.

handle_cast(die, _) ->
  io:format("~p Dying ~n",[self()]),
  exit(normal).

handle_info(Info, State) ->
  io:format("Unkown message ~p for state ~p~n", [Info, State]).

terminate(Reason, State) ->
  io:format("~p Died because ~p with state ~p~n", [self(), Reason, State]).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of `gen_server:call/2,3` is to wrap into a function call the passing of a message into a `gen_server` process and the reception of its reply. If you want to deal only with messages, don't use `gen_server:call/2,3` but rather have the caller invoke `gen_server:cast/2` and include the caller pid in the message:

```
send(Worker, Ref, Counter) ->
    gen_server:cast(Worker, {inc, Ref, Counter, self()}).
```

Then have `gen_server:handle_cast/2` understand that message and use the pid send the reply back to the caller:

```
handle_cast({inc, Ref, Data, From}, Limit) ->
    From ! {Ref, updated, Data+1},
    {noreply, Limit-1}.
```

By the way, note that when you choose this sort of approach, you need to deal with possible failure. If you pass a message to the `gen_server` process but it dies before it sends you a reply, you need to make sure the caller doesn't sit and wait forever for a reply that will never arrive. The best way to do this is with a [monitor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) — you can have the caller monitor the `gen_server` process before sending it a message and [demonitor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#demonitor-1) it once it receives the reply. If the `gen_server` process dies, the caller will get a `DOWN` message instead (see [the `monitor` documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) for details). Also note that by doing this you're reimplementing a bunch of what `gen_server:call/2,3` already does for you.

Comment: Thanks this has been very helpful. My confusion comes from the fact that I am trying to get two gen_servers to talk back and forth to each other. I cant figure out how to make the back and forth messaging work if they are both waiting in the gen_server loop.

Comment: The `gen_server:handle_info/2` function handles the reception of regular messages. You can send messages from it or from one of the other `gen_server` callback functions.